# How to correctly register in my DNS servers whose IPs and names are handled by someone else?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I use a virtual server (several similar cases) set up and registered by someone else. Its IP is `10.0.0.1` and name `a.example.com` (both handled by the "someone else" above).

I manage the domain `sub.example.com` and would like to also register this server as `b.sub.example.com`.

There are two ways of doing this in my DNS: either

```
b IN CNAME a.example.com.
```

or

```
b IN A 10.0.0.1
```

Since the IP is not distributed by DHCP (it is therefore hardcoded in the server config) there will be a problem in either case if it changes without me knowing and neither solution above would help. The `PTR` will point to `a.example.com` (I do not control the IP reverse mapping)

So what is the proper way (= canonical / best practice) to do the registration on my side?

**EDIT**: since `b` is also referenced in the `NS` I will have to go for the second solution. Please see [my answer below](https://serverfault.com/a/586099/78319) for details.

I accepted [MadHatter](https://serverfault.com/users/55514/madhatter)'s answer because even though it does not address the best practices / standards for the case above (before the `NS` update which forces a solution anyway) it gives interesting insights. Thanks!

Comment: You talk to the person in charge and get him do his part of the job?

Comment: @TomTom: everyone did their job. The virtualization group registered the servers in the correct domain (from their perspective) and I want to register them in mine (for various reasons).

Comment: Is this IP address static or not?

Comment: @MadHatter: it is static (I mentioned in my question that DHCP is not used and the IP is hardcoded in the server - it is actually automatically reserved (and communicated to me) and updated in the `example.com` DNS)

Comment: So why do you fear it changing without your knowledge?

Comment: @MadHatter: I do not particularly fear it changing - what I meant is that neither of the solutions would protect me from a change of the IP  (as opposed to having, say, `myowngoogle IN CNAME www.google.com` which would automatically adapt to changes on the `www.google.com`server). This is why the question is about best practices and possibly standards in such a registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS isn't well-designed to handle changes in static IP addresses without manual intervention.  There are technologies for allowing records to be propagated automatically, such as [TSIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSIG), but they require quite a lot of co-operative setup, and even then don't deal well with changes to PTR records.

Manual IP changes happen all the time in the real world. They have to be scheduled well in advance, and handled appropriately. That involves well-timed and thoughtful changes to the DNS, the acceptance that DNS propagation is imperfect and that there will be business effects as a result of the change, and a consequent dislike of such changes.

TomTom's comment above is right; if everyone involved does their jobs, a change will go through with the minimum of effort - but some effort **will** be needed.

Comment: I completely understand this and it is not my question. I know that a change of the IP will break both of the configurations and that the `PTR` will point to the example.com entry. Now since both of the configurations work I wanted to understand if one is preferred over the other.

Answer (score 1):

I will finally **have** to use

```
b IN A 10.0.0.1
```

because `b` is also referenced in the `NS` record (which I did not pay attention to intially)

```
 IN NS b
```

It is illegal for `b` to be a `CNAME` so there is no choice but to go with the explicit `A` record.

Answer (score 0):

The CNAME option will still work, as you say their infrastructure knows of the VPS's IP and they properly update their nameservers.

EDIT: About the PTR record; the only thing you can do is ask them. I myself have a few  hosted VMs and all my providers except for one agreed to it. If their policy allows it you are fine.

Comment: That won't fix the PTR issue.